Multithreading with cudf
I want to spawn multiple threads on gpu. Something like the code snippet I have attached. Doing this throws an error MemoryError: std::bad_alloc: CUDA error at: rapids/include/rmm/mr/device/cuda_memory_resource.hpp:60: cudaErrorIllegalAddress an illegal memory access was encountered
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
import cudf 
def func(x):
    print(x)
    X_test = pd.read_csv("temp.csv")
    X_test = cudf.from_pandas(X_test)
    return len(X_test)+x

def get_stats_internal_with_gpu(stats_arg):
    gpu_id = np.random.randint(2) 
    cp.cuda.Device(gpu_id).use()  # Assign the GPU
    return func(stats_arg)  # Your existing GPU code

# Parallelize across GPUs
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=510) as executor:
    chunk_results = list(executor.map( get_stats_internal_with_gpu,list(range(50))
    ))

print(chunk_results)

Any help regarding this will be appreciated

"I want to spawn multiple threads on gpu" This is not possible (at least, not using the same definition of threads than CPU ones). You can only spawn kernels on GPUs which are inherently parallel. Using multiple CPU threads to spawn multiple kernels in parallel is generally useless (even often detrimental for performance) unless you spawn a kernel on different GPUs. Please read the CUDA programming guide to better know how (Nvidia) GPUs work.

By the way, are you sure the API is thread-safe? I think it is better to use multiprocessing here. This introduce a significant data movement overhead, but this is the case for GPU transfer anyway (the PCIe/NvLink interconnect is actually even slower than the RAM).

For this kind of multi-GPU work with cuDF in Python, you're probably better served using Dask cuDF, which relies on Dask and Dask-CUDA.
Dask makes it easy to execute an arbitrary function on each partition of a larger dataset with map_partitions, if your necessary operations aren't supported by default (len is supported).
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

dask.config.set({"dataframe.backend": "cudf"})

import cudf # for use inside custom function
from dask_cuda import LocalCUDACluster
from dask.distributed import Client

cluster = LocalCUDACluster() # use every GPU on machine by default
client = Client(cluster)

df = dd.read_csv(...) # read file into distributed dataset
df.map_partitions(custom_func) # run your function on each partition

